# Add list to a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
var columnNames = (from autoExport in dataContext.AutoExports
               where autoExport.AutoExportTemplate != null
                  && ContainsColumn(autoExport.AutoExportTemplate, realName)
               select GetDbColumnNames(autoExport.AutoExportTemplate, realName)).ToList();
```

Where the function `GetDbColumns()` returns an `List<string>`.
So columNames is of the type `List<List<string>>`.
Is it possible to create a `List<string>`, so each element of the list of GetDbColumns is added to the result of the LinQ query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the "select many" construction:

```
var columnNames = (
    from autoExport in dataContext.AutoExports
    where autoExport.AutoExportTemplate != null
          && ContainsColumn(autoExport.AutoExportTemplate, realName)
    from column in GetDbColumnNames(autoExport.AutoExportTemplate, realName)
    select column).ToList();
```

Or here is an alternative way of using `SelectMany`:

```
var columnNames = (
    from autoExport in dataContext.AutoExports
    where autoExport.AutoExportTemplate != null
          && ContainsColumn(autoExport.AutoExportTemplate, realName)
    select autoExport
).SelectMany(x => x.GetDbColumnNames(autoExport.AutoExportTemplate, realName))
.ToList();
```

And finally, this is another way to put it (but it includes the somewhat ugly code `x => x`):

```
var columnNames = (
    from autoExport in dataContext.AutoExports
    where autoExport.AutoExportTemplate != null
          && ContainsColumn(autoExport.AutoExportTemplate, realName)
    select autoExport.GetDbColumnNames(autoExport.AutoExportTemplate, realName)
).SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```